# Common value in 2 groups of values with Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have alphanumeric values in 2 groups of values, on 2 different tabs:

[image]

I have the A value and the G value, and I need the value associated with each of them that is repeated in both groups (D). Someone who dominates `QUERY` maybe can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER({A2:B; D2:E}, COUNTIF({B2:B; D2:D}, {B2:B; D2:D})>1)
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1&C1, QUERY({'Page 1'!A2:A&
 IFNA(VLOOKUP('Page 1'!C2:C, 'Page 2'!C2:D, 2, 0)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP('Page 1'!C2:C, 'Page 2'!C2:D, 1, 0))}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the question well, what happens is that the groups are repeated with different values throughout each sheet. Your formula gives me an error, so I need a formula that contains 2 values: A and G in this case. I have updated the image so that it is better understood.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls with example of desired result

Comment: OK: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15OUDgt-4q2itgRxkNGBY9hkWx8WzttC5mStY0KKJYEU/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Wow!, I was far away... Thank you very much.